# CSS - screensize minus constant

Tags: css

Is it possible somehow to calculate size of an element as a basic mathematical expression?
e.g.:

```
.wideColumn{max-width:100%-20em;} /*not working*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). But unfortunately it cannot be done with pure CSS.

There are, however, workarounds to this issue using pure CSS. For example:

```
.wideColumn {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10em;
    margin-left: 10em;
}
```

Of course, this example may not work with your code. But there are numerous other workarounds.

Comment: I finally solved it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **NO** you cannot, not atleast in CSS 2, 2.1 spec, then too if you are interested you could take a look at Dynamic stylesheets with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Or as [Sandeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567751/sandeep) told, you can use `calc()` which is introduced in CSS3 spec

[Reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/)

Comment: Right, try less or javascript.

Comment: There is a **calc** property

Comment: @sandeep that was something new, edited my answer, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in CSS directly, but try something like LESS - http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

it might be available one day, but not now - read more here http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs#math